# How to use paramiko.ServerInterface to response exec request

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

An OpenSSH server on Ubuntu, for example, can response to `ssh [username@]hostname [command]`, do this single [command] and response.

For example,

```
me@ubuntu:~$ ssh 127.0.0.1 ls
Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Videos
me@ubuntu:~$
```

Question is:

- How to achieve this kind of server with [paramiko.ServerInstance](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/server.html)?
- How to control the input and output to local shell's stdin and stdout?

One more question is, what if the background command handler is not an standard shell, but a implementation by something like [sshim](https://github.com/simon-engledew/sshim)?

Answer (score 0):

`paramiko.ServerInstance` actually gives a hook to implement and with this `check_channel_exec_request`, you can call *command* locally and use *channel* to send, recv or close.

**check_channel_exec_request**(*channel*, *command*)

```
Determine if a shell command will be executed for the client. 
If this method returns True, the channel should be connected 
to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the shell command.

The default implementation always returns `False`.
```

**Parameters:**

- channel ([*Channel*](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel)) – the **Channel** the request arrived on.
- command ([*str*](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#str)) – the command to execute.

**Returns:**

- `True` if this channel is now hooked up to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the executing command
- `False` if the command will not be executed.